# Show $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\sqrt{x+3}$ is continuous at $x=1$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given then 
let $\delta=min\left\{2, \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right\}$

Want to show $| f(x) - f(1)| \lt \epsilon$, if $|x-1| \lt \delta$

Max value of $\delta$ is $2$, so $|x-1| \lt 2 \implies x \in (1,3)$
$\implies x=3$ is the max $x$ value

$\left| f(x)-f(1) \right| = \left| f(x)-f(1) \right| = $
$\left| \sqrt{x+3}-2 \right| = $
$\left| (\sqrt{x+3}-2)  \frac{\sqrt{x+3}+2}{\sqrt{x+3}+2} \right| = ...$

$\left| \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x+3}+2} \right|=$
$\left| x-1 \right| . \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+3}+2} \right| \lt $
$\frac{\epsilon}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}+2} \lt \epsilon$

$\Box$

Edit (Second attempt):

let $\delta=min\left\{1, \left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)\epsilon \right\}$

Then $x \in (0,2)$

$\left| \sqrt{x+3} -2 \right| = \left| x-1 \right| \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+3} +2}$
$\lt \epsilon(\sqrt{3}+2) \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+2} = \epsilon \ \ \ \ \ \Box$

Comment: Why can't $x$ be 0?

Comment: It can be. I made no such assumption in the proof though.

Comment: $|x-1|\left|\frac1{\sqrt{x+3}+2}\right|<|x-1|<\delta$

Comment: I guess I could have just gone with $\delta = min\left\{2, \epsilon \right\}$

Comment: There is  a mistake in the last-but-one inequality. $x <3$ is useless here.

Comment: Also $\sqrt{x+3}+2<\sqrt6+2$ so $\frac1{|\sqrt{x+3}+2|}>\frac1{\sqrt6+2}$

Comment: Yes, I see the mistake now. Thanks both of you.

Comment: Btw.: $|x-1|< 2 \Leftrightarrow \color{red}{-1} <x<3$.

Comment: Oh gosh! Thanks @trancelocation. So many mistakes!

Comment: Added 2nd attempt of my proof in the edit above. Basically let $\delta=min\left\{1, \left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)\epsilon \right\}$

Comment: Second attempt is correct.

Comment: One possible way is to argue that $a\colon x\mapsto \sqrt x$ and $b\colon x\mapsto x$ and $c\colon x\mapsto 5$ are continuous. Thus $f(x)=(a\circ(b+c))(x)$ is continuous while we assume the domain of $f$ is $[-3,\infty)$

Comment: Terminology nitpick: we can't have $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ if $f(x)=\sqrt{x+3}$ is all the definition we have for $f$. At best we can have $f:[-3,\infty)\to\Bbb R$. This doesn't affect the behaviour at $x=1$, so it's not terribly important this time.

Comment: Ah! Good point.